# CSS: Set 3 items list in row fixed position

Tags: css

I have a clickable button surrounded by two words, the button switching between the  style of the words (bold or not). this is the code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="selectorContainer">
    <li class="option1">
      <span>Option 1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="arrowCtn"> 
      <button class="arrowsImgBtn" (click)="somefunc()">
        <img src="../../assets/images/arrow.png">
      </button> 
    </li>
    <li class="option2">
      <span>Option 2</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}

.selectorContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background: #f9f9f8;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    min-height: 74px;
}
```

THe button is toggle between style bold of the options..

But when I click on it, it moves from it's position a bit since it's a row and the boldness is pushing it a bit forward..

I'm trying to make the button locked in the position and the words to be relative to it

How can I stabilize the button to not move at all from it's position?

Comment: position absolute on the button

Comment: I tried it, but it makes the words overlay the button

Answer (score 0):

Use a class to make `Option 1` width a constant value.

```css
.wrapper {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}

.selectorContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background: #f9f9f8;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    min-height: 74px;
}

.placeholder {
  display:block;
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="selectorContainer">
    <li class="option1">
      <span class="placeholder">Option 1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="arrowCtn"> 
      <button class="arrowsImgBtn" (click)="somefunc()">
        <img src="../../assets/images/arrow.png">
      </button> 
    </li>
    <li class="option2">
      <span>Option 2</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @RoiSadika sorry, I missed `display:block;`, please try again.
and 85px may not be exact value, because now the text is not bold.
You should pick the correct value. 90px, for example.

Comment: Sorry my friend, it's not working and also I think if we specify a hard values it may affect the responsive

Comment: @RoiSadika
run my code snippet,
open dev tools,
add `font-weight: bold;` for `Option 1`. toggle it on/off. the button holds in the same position

Comment: @RoiSadika very strange, it works for me in dev tools